# file does not exist using DATA_DIR and DATA_FILE? Why?

Tags: python, csv, directory, data-science, filenotfoundexception

When i run a file from my school, the code gives me this error:

```
error> reading data fileError tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in line 42, saw 3
```

The file and the folder both exist in my desktop but for some reason i cant view the file...
I am using `DATA_DIR` and `DATA_FILE` variables.

Can you help so that the code does find and read the folder/file contents?

CODE:

```
import requests
import nltk
import textblob
import os
import glob
import csv
import pandas as pd
import sys

DEBUGGING = True
TOP_MOST = 10
#
#   Stopwords file:
stopwords = open("english-stop-words-large.txt")
stopwords = stopwords.read()
#print(stopwords)

DATA_DIR = 'DM.CW2'
DATA_FILES = 'benjamin-bunny.txt'

# txtFile = open("kim.txt")
# txtFile = txtFile.read()
try:
    df = pd.read_csv((DATA_FILES), na_filter=False)
except Exception as x:
    print ('error> reading data file' + str(x))
    sys.exit()

for (j, myfile) in zip(range(len(DATA_DIR)), DATA_FILES):
    with open( myfile) as f:
        raw_verse = f.read()
    f.close()
    if (DEBUGGING):
        print('raw_verse=', raw_verse)
    print('file=', myfile)


freq_words = [dict() for j in range(len(DATA_FILES))]

verse = textblob.TextBlob(raw_input().decode('utf-8'))
if DEBUGGING:
    print('verse=', verse)

    words = {}
    for w in verse.word_counts:
        if w not in stopwords:
            words[w] = verse.word_counts[w]
    if DEBUGGING:
        print(words)

sorted_words = sorted(words, key=words.__getitem__, reverse=True)
for (i, w) in zip(range(TOP_MOST), sorted_words):
    freq_words[j][w] = verse.word_counts[w]
    print(i, w, verse.word_counts[w])

#   For polarity and subjectivity:
testimonial = textblob.TextBlob(words)
print(testimonial.sentiment)
```

The folder which contains the .txt file is called DM.CW2. Its on my desktop. The file .txt file is also inside this folder.

I am using python 2.7. and i believe i imported all the required packages for this.

Comment: Note: `len(DATA_DIR)` is `6`, i.e. the length of the string.

Comment: It would be helpful if you add the exact errors you're getting. Unless the DATA_FILES are in the same directory as the script it will not be able to find it. Try and put the absolute path, e.g. '/home/user/project/DM.CW2/benjamin-bunny.txt'

Comment: I tried but it still didnt find the directory. And the error is exactly: error> reading data fileError tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in line 42, saw 3.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say exactly what is happening without your data file. Maybe add it to the question.

The error you're getting "Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in line 3, saw 12" implies that the program is able to find the file but have problems reading it.

There are a few possible issues but it's impossible to tell without seeing the data in the file. Check the following:

1. The extension is `.txt` not `.csv` so `pandas.read_csv` may not be the right method for reading the file - it really is a question of what is the file format.
2. The default file separator is a comma, but your file may have a different separator such as a space of a tab. You can try with different separators

```
data = pd.read_csv('file1.csv', sep='\t')
or
data = pd.read_csv('file1.csv', sep=' ')
```

3. In case is it a CSV file it may have corrupt lines, so you can use the following in order to skip them

`data = pd.read_csv('file1.csv', error_bad_lines=False)`

Comment: I tried this fix but didnt work. I do know that pandas can read any file with the read_csv function. I managed to find another way to implement my code. Thanks for the time. Ill accept this answer as correct as i believe this is the problem.